# Possible to tag a logic app run with some notes?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way I can tag a single run execution of a logic app with some notes or details during the execution? I want to be able to search for a particular run using some string stored on the unique run. If this isn't doable, does anyone recommend a good workaround for accomplishing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the run id and persist it.

[image]

[image]

Later, you could use this run id in the Runs history tab to go directly to the instance you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> search for a particular run using some string stored on the unique run

You can also grab the run id and use it for other tracking by initializing it to a variable in logic app also by using below expression in workflow:

```
workflow()['run']['name']
```

I used initializing a variable action:

[image]

***Then save it***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

***References taken from:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#workflow

I couldnt find Print run identifier action neither in standard nor in consumption:

[image]